# Comparing problem with If else statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two condition of my same JSON data:

```
{  
   "selectionId":124,
   "selectionDate":"2070-01-01",
   "selectionAudit":null,
   "letter":[  
      {  
         "letterNo":13,
         "letterId":1,
         "inout":"out",
         "inoutNo":"12332466544",
         "inoutDate":"2070-01-01",
         "letterIssuedSubBy":null,
         "letterFile":null,
         "representativeName":null,
         "representativeNameEng":null,
         "selectionId":124,
         "assessmentNo":null,
         "entryBy":"user98",
         "rStatus":"I",
         "others":null,
         "signatary":"qwerrt",
         "letterBox":null,
         "imageFile":null,
         "imageTitle":null,
         "reminderYesNo":"N"
      }
   ]
}
```

Same JSON with letter array empty structure :

```
  {  
       "selectionId":124,
       "selectionDate":"2070-01-01",
       "selectionAudit":null,
       "letter":[]
    }
```

All these values are stored in 
 **var trDataSecondTable;** . I tried to compare if the `letter` is empty or not by using if condition:

```
  if(trDataSecondTable.letter != null) {
            console.log("asasfasdfdsfdsfds");
         $("#inoutDate").val(trDataSecondTable.letter[0].inoutDate);
         $("#inoutNo").val(trDataSecondTable.letter[0].inoutNo);
         $("#signatary").val(trDataSecondTable.letter[0].signatary);
     }
     else
     {
         console.log("entered in else part");
     }
```

Though `"letter":[]` is empty it is not entering into else part. While comparing i also tried **trDataSecondTable.letter.length != 0** but also it is not entering into else part.

Comment: an empty array has the `length` of zero, and not `null`.

Comment: `While comparing i also tried trDataSecondTable.letter.length != 0 but also it is not entering into else part` That is the correct method to check for an empty array. There must be another issue in you logic.

Comment: Be sure `[] == null` or `[] === null` returns `false`

Comment: if(typeof array != "undefined" && array != null && array.length != null && array.length > 0){}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this condition is enough

```
if(trDataSecondTable.letter.length)
```

Comment: It can be dangerous to dereference the length property without checking if letter is null or undefined first, even more with raw data.

Answer (score 4):

Your condition should **check for both `null` and the length**:

```
if (trDataSecondTable.letter != null && trDataSecondTable.letter.length > 0)
```

Is is important to check for `null` before accessing the `length` property as it guarantees you won't try to access the `length` property on `null`, which would raise an exception. This is important since data is rarely reliable.

Because of the `&&` operator, if the first check fails, the second check won't be evaluated.

Actually, an even safer way would be to check if the value is truthy, as this will work for `null` and `undefined`:

```
if (trDataSecondTable.letter && trDataSecondTable.letter.length > 0)
```

Comment: can you tell why he should check for both?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the `length` of the array.

```
if (trDataSecondTable.letter.length) {
    // letter has some elements
} else {
    // no elements
}
```